# How does `#[codec(mel_bound())]` work?

Tags: storage, frame, scale-codec, generics

When declaring types, with generic parameters, to be stored in runtime storage, it’s common to see this pattern

```rust
#[derive(Encode, Decode, MaxEncodedLen, TypeInfo)]
pub struct MyItem<TypeA, TypeB> {
    pub item_a: TypeA,
    pub item_b: TypeB,
}

type MyItemOf<T> = MyItem<<T as Config>::TypeA, <T as Config>::TypeB>;
```

However, this seems a bit clunky, and I have tried the following

```rust
#[derive(Encode, Decode, MaxEncodedLen, TypeInfo)]
pub struct MyItem<T: Config> {
    pub item_a: T::TypeA,
    pub item_b: T::TypeB,
}
```

only to get an error saying that `T` doesn’t implement `TypeInfo`. This is what I ran into in the past, so I've used the first pattern above for some time.

There’s a way to get the second approach above to work by using [`#[scale_info(skip_type_params(..))]`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/scale_info/index.html#scale_infoskip_type_params) to tell `scale_info` to ignore that `T` doesn't implement `TypeInfo`.

Still, I run into the error that `MyItem<T>` doesn't implement `parity_scale_codec::MaxEncodedLen`. I've looked around and found that the [Substrate Kitties tutorial](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/kitties/pt1/#scaffold-kitty-struct) uses the `#[codec(mel_bound)]` attribute on its `Kitty<T>` struct. I found that it also works in my case and I ended up with

```rust
#[derive(Encode, Decode, MaxEncodedLen, TypeInfo)]
#[scale_info(skip_type_params(T))]
#[codec(mel_bound())]
pub struct MyItem<T: Config> {
    pub item_a: T::TypeA,
    pub item_b: T::TypeB,
}
```

However, I don't quite understand how `#[codec(mel_bound())]` works and what are the tradeoffs involved with it. I couldn't find much documentation around it. Would anyone be kind enough to explain how it works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`skip_type_params(T)` boils down to the same as `mel_bound()`, both will have an empty where-bound for the implementation of `MaxEncodedLen`. The advantage of `skip_type_params` is that if there are more generic parameters it is easier to skip single ones, while `mel_bound()` skips all generic parameters.

By default the macro will put the following where-bound: `T: MaxEncodedLen`. As you already have seen, this is wrong. So, we have the `mel_bound` attribute which lets you as a developer write the where-bound manually. You could write `mel_bound(T::TypeA: MaxEncodedLen, T::TypeB: MaxEncodedLen)` and it would compile as well. However, you don't need this because you probably have the bound on `TypeA: MaxEncodedLen` in your trait declaration. So, you just write `mel_bound()` to get an empty where-bound.

There is actually an issue to also add `skip_type_params` support to scale-codec: https://github.com/paritytech/parity-scale-codec/issues/316

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I hope these things can be unified in the future with `skip_type_params`